# Viewstate in PHP

Tags: php, forms, viewstate

Is it possible to enable viewstate in PHP? 
The one where you input the value and the value stays there even when you refresh the page. 
If yes, a brief explanation on how it works is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know the closes thing to what you want is a $_SESSION variable. But what do you want to monitor?

Comment: A registration form. And also an upload form.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any such thing in PHP, but you can use PHP sessions to store the variable even when page loads and you can use those values later.